# Group by in Stimulsoft Report

Tags: c#, report, stimulsoft

I have a Data Source as show below:

Name - GroupName - price

I send this data source to my report and want to show this result in view to user:

GroupName - Count - PricePercentOfAll

In fact Group by GroupName in stimulsoft report.

How can I do it in Stimulsoft report designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a GroupHeader, put a text component with a summary on it and use Totals function to calculate the percentage.